# How to loop all code for different quizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I want to loop all of this code to have 3 different quizzes, is that possible or do I have to repeat all of this code two more times?

Each quiz should have 3 different questions, along with 3 different answers to each of those questions. Then there should be different a different alert in each of the quizzes that depending on how many questions the user answered correctly.

**Desired Outcome:** 3 different quizzes, using the same code to move through each question, all displaying a different end alert.

```js
var iconquiz = [{
    "question": "which icon is used for GitHub",
    "answers": ["<i class='fa fa-gitlab fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-github-alt fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-grav fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
    "correct": 2,
    "was_correct": 0
  },
  {
    "question": "What icon is this?<i class='fa fa-gitlab fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
    "answers": ["GitHub", "Google", "GitLab"],
    "correct": 3,
    "was_correct": 0
  },
  {
    "question": "which icone is used by PayPal?",
    "answers": ["<i class='fa fa-pinterest-square' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-pied-piper-pp' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-paypal' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
    "correct": 3,
    "was_correct": 0
  }
];

//console.log(quiz[0].answers);
var index = -1;
var correct = 0;

function nextButton() {
  if (index < iconquiz.length - 1) {
    index++;

    document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].question;
    document.getElementById("answer1.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' data-question=" + index + " value='1' >" + iconquiz[index].answers[0];
    document.getElementById("answer2.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' data-question=" + index + " value='2' >" + iconquiz[index].answers[1];
    document.getElementById("answer3.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' value='3' data-question=" + index + " name='answer'>" + iconquiz[index].answers[2];

    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("answers");
    for (radio in radios) {
      radios[radio].onchange = function() {

        if (iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct == 0) {
          if (iconquiz[this.dataset.question].correct == this.value) {
            correct++;
            iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct = 1;
          }
        } else if (iconquiz[this.dataset.question].correct != this.value) {
          correct--;
          iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct = 0;
        }

        console.log(correct);
      }
    }


  } else {
    alert("Correct answers :" + correct);
  }


}

function prevButton() {
  if (index > 0) {
    index--;
    document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].question;
    document.getElementById("answer1.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' data-question=" + index + " value='1' >" + iconquiz[index].answers[0];
    document.getElementById("answer2.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' data-question=" + index + " value='2' >" + iconquiz[index].answers[1];
    document.getElementById("answer3.0").innerHTML = "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' data-question=" + index + " value='3' >" + iconquiz[index].answers[2];
  }
}
```

```css
/*************
MAIN STUFFF
*************/

body {
  background: #CCC;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.collapse {
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


/*************
QUIZ BOXES
*************/

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.answers {
  display: inline;
  visibility: visible;
}

label {
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4ada95;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #494949;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label::before {}


/************
QUIZ CONTENT
************/

h3 {
  background-color: #707070;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #707070;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #707070;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 73px;
}


/***********
QUIZES
***********/

#expand,
#expand2,
#expand3 {
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background-color: #4ada95;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/**********
FIRST QUIZ
**********/

#toggle:checked~#expand {
  height: 0px;
}

#toggle:checked~label::before {
  display: hidden;
}


/**********
SECOND QUIZ
**********/

#toggle2:checked~#expand2 {
  height: 0px;
}

#toggle2:checked~label::before {
  display: hidden;
}


/**********
THIRD QUIZ
**********/

#toggle3:checked~#expand3 {
  height: 0px;
}

#toggle3:checked~label::before {
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="collapse">
      <h2>Icon Quiz</h2>
      <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label for="toggle">take quiz</label>
      <div id="expand">
        <section>
          <h3 id="questionHere">Please Begin</h3>
          <section>
            <li id="answer1.0">This is a quiz over different icons used in the coding community!</li>
            <li id="answer2.0">Click next when you're ready!</li>
            <li id="answer3.0"></li>
          </section>
        </section>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button onclick="prevButton()" type="button">prev</button><button onclick="nextButton()" type="button">next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse">
      <h2>Another Quiz</h2>
      <input id="toggle2" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label for="toggle2">take quiz</label>
      <div id="expand2">
        <section>
          <h3>test?</h3>
          <section>
            <li>blah</li>
            <li>blah</li>
            <li>blah</li>
          </section>
        </section>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button onclick="prevButton()" type="button">prev</button><button onclick="nextButton()" type="button">next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse">
      <h2>Another Quiz</h2>
      <input id="toggle3" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label for="toggle3">take quiz</label>
      <div id="expand3">
        <section>
          <h3>test?</h3>
          <li>blah</li>
          <li>blah</li>
          <li>blah</li>
        </section>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button onclick="prevButton()" type="button">prev</button><button onclick="nextButton()" type="button">next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>






  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My friend i think you should take a look to custom elements (web-components) : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/building-components/customelements

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible without repeating your code two more times. Somewhere, you will have an array or object containing the quiz questions for each quiz, such as `[iconQuiz, secondQuiz, thirdQuiz]`. Then you will loop over that array or object to make the "take quiz" buttons specifically link to those quiz questions.